# subprocess call on python gives Error "Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python, subprocess, file-descriptor

Whenever i call a c code executable from Python using the method below I get a "Bad file descriptor" error. When I run the code from the command prompt it works fine. Help please!?

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.call(['C:\Working\Python\celp.exe', '-o', 'ofile'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

In [84]: %run "C:\Working\Python\test.py"
Error: : Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: How do you know the program has been written in C and not in C++, Pascal, Modula, Fortran, Cobol or Brainfuck?

Comment: Or any other language that compiles to .exe

Comment: Please provide a traceback. What happend when you run this code outside of `IPython`?

Comment: 1- use raw string literal for Windows paths (otherwise the backslash may have a special meaning inside a literal): `r'C:\Users\..'` 2- to discard possible input, use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`

Comment: I compiled and edited the code myself

Comment: @ppperry how do you do a trace back in python?

Comment: @Olaf I compiled and edited the code myself

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian "stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL" doesn't work, I get an attribute error.

Comment: If you use Python 2 then you should mention it. What happens if you put `subprocess.DEVNULL` into google? Try `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried "DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)" to no luck

Comment: 1- "to no luck" is not very informative. Do you mean that it doesn't fix *"Bad file descriptor"* error? If your intent is to provide empty input to the subprocess; you should use `stdin=DEVNULL` instead of `stdin=PIPE` regardless. 2-  Your original question is unclear: *" When I run the code from the command prompt it works fine."* -- do you mean `test.py` works or `celp.exe` works if you run it directly? What version of IPython do you use? Do you have `readline` installed? Can you reproduce the error without `celp.exe` (run a dummy child python script instead).

Comment: Update. I don't think this was a file descriptor error. i think this is a working directory error. The cwd of the subprocess shows as "/cygdrive/c/Working/Python" when it needs to be "C:/Working/Python".

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to add the stdout flag. add `stdout = subprocess.PIPE`, like this:

```
p = subprocess.call(
    ['C:\Working\Python\celp.exe', '-o', 'ofile'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # needed for the next line to be sensible
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
```

now, try run your script again

Answer (score -6):

Try this

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.call(['C:\Working\Python\celp.exe', '-o', 'ofile'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True)
```